# How to debug transaction commit in sybase?

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I have a transaction based application and it rolls the operation back on an error.  However
in some cases, the rollback doesn't happen. ( Though its getting called from the application). Ours is a very complex application and there are chances that some code is directly committing the data.  Is there a way to debug the commit to the database?  (Either from java or from the database?). From java, we are not able to do this because, java.sql.Connection is an interface and the implementation is provided by sybase jconnect for which we don't have the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this will help, but with this [driver](http://ppewww.physics.gla.ac.uk/~tdoherty/Octopus/OctopusPatch/octopus-3.0/docs/extras/tools/p6spy/index.htm), this helps in tracing all the DML operations you perform on the database including commit & rollback. When you use [p6spy](http://www.findjar.com/jar/p6spy/p6spy/1.3/p6spy-1.3.jar.html?all=true)
it logs every database hit into a log file, from where you can easily figure out where your application is performing a commit.

Apart from the above suggestion, I fell every database comes with some sort of monitoring tools, which with you can monitor which DML is fired within a span of time.